# rotating image javascript--image doesn't rotate--MVC3

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3

So this code SHOULD work...the exact same thing works if I use a text editor and a plain html document. Perhaps there is something in visual studio I need to configure?

I am trying to rotate the following four images every five seconds. Here is the JScript1.js file:

```
var imageArray = ["http://localhost:53734/Content/themes/base/images/oly1.jpg",   "http://localhost:53734/Content/themes/base/images/oly2.jpg", "http://localhost:53734/Content/themes/base/images/oly3.jpg", "http://localhost:53734/Content/themes/base/images/oly4.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;
var myImage = document.getElementById("rotatingBanner");


function changeImage() {
myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
imageIndex++;
if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
}
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

and here is the view in which it runs:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<h4>View results by:</h4>
<ul id="friend">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Countries", "Countries", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Events", "Events", "Home")</li>
</ul>
<div>
<img id="rotatingBanner" src="http://localhost:53734/Content/themes/base/images/oly1.jpg" />
</div>
<script src="http://localhost:53734/Scripts/JScript1.js"/>
```

The image we ask for in the view shows up, but it doesn't rotate after 5 seconds like it should.

Comment: Everything looks alrite, isn't that cached version of JScript1.js or something like that?

Comment: Agree it looks fine.  I'd check with Firebug for any script errors, then try adding a breakpoint to trace the code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't close off the script tag appropriately: 
It should have been closed with

```
</script>
```

NOT

```
script.js/>
```